# WebAssembly InstantiateStreaming Wrong MIME type

Tags: javascript, rust, streaming, fetch-api, webassembly

I am attempting to get this tutorial (here: https://www.hellorust.com/demos/add/index.html) to work, and it seems that whatever I do, I cannot get the WebAssembly MDN reserved function to properly work.

So, I followed the instructions on the link above and got an `add.wasm` file. As far as I can tell this should be fairly simple and should work. After a little digging I found that the newest WebAssembly module is to instantiate streaming - the documentation for which can be found here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API).

The MDN example says to do the following:

```
var importObject = {
  imports: { imported_func: arg => console.log(arg) }
};
```

then

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('simple.wasm'), importObject)
.then(obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func());
```

According to MDN the importObject is to unwrap the nested argument. Weird, but OK.

To make this as simple as possible I put the `add.wasm` file and the `js` file that would import it in the same directory and then did then following (**NOTE**: I am using Vue.js, but for anyone familiar with SPA like libraries this should be similar):

```
window.WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('./add.wasm', {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/wasm",
  },
}), importObject)
.then(obj => {
  console.log('inside return obj from WebAssembly initiateStreaming')
  obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func() 
})
.catch(error=>{
  console.log('there was some error; ', error)
});
```

The error I get back is:

```
there was some error;  TypeError: "Response has unsupported MIME type"
```

I've tried not adding the header to the fetch request, using `fetch(add.wasm)`, dropping the `window.`, dropping the `importObject` entirely and simple logging `obj` to console. Nothing appears to work.

It may be that I have to add the `application/wasm` field to webpack somehow if it is not widely supported, but I'm not sure and I haven't seen any examples online.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

EDIT:

Someone suggested that since this was a fetch request it had to be making the request from a backend server. This made sense to me, so I did the following:

```
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('http://localhost:8000/files/add.wasm'), importObject)
    .then(obj => {
      console.log('inside return obj from WebAssembly initiateStreaming')
      obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func()
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('there was some error; ', error)
    });
```

Where `http://localhost:8000/files/{someFile}` is a backend route that serves my files (which I made sure to put `add.wasm` in of course). Unfortunately, I get the same error (i.e. `unrecognized MIME type`) and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Discussion in ##javascript on freenode revealed that OP is using golang's http `ServeFile` method.

Comment: thanks buddy! Yes, if anyone knows how to change the headers for the MIME type on ServeFile please let me know - I'm looking into it now.

Comment: got it - answer was what snek said. Thanks snek.

Answer (score 12):

Considering you can't change the server to properly return `application/wasm` for `.wasm` file requests for any reason, you can work around the issue by changing the way you instantiate the WebAssembly module. Instead of doing this:

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("./add.wasm")).then(obj => /* ... */)
```

Do this:

```
const response = await fetch("add.wasm");
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const obj = await WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer);
obj.instance.exports.exported_func();
```

Or the equivalent using `then()` if you cannot use `async/await`.

In practice, what my workaround does is to avoid calling `instantiateStreaming()`, which must check the MIME type returned by the server before proceeding (according to [this specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wasm-web-api-1/#streaming-modules)). Instead, I call `instantiate()` passing an `ArrayBuffer` and avoid the check altogether.

Comment: thanks for the workaround..but i get this: CompileError: "wasm validation error: at offset 4: failed to match magic number"

Comment: Not sure what could be wrong. What MIME type is the server sending? I suggest making the request using Postman and analyzing the response. It will probably give you some clue.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting `TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object.` However, the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate) say that it should be optional?

Comment: @Exr0n If for example you're using Golang WASM, you would add go.importObject after the buffer argument in the WebAssembly.instantiate() call.

Comment: @Alex Do you know how it's done in rust? Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Exr0n I would reference wasm_exec.js that Go's wasm environment uses (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b2fcfc1a50fbd46556f7075f7f1fbf600b5c9e5d/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js#L176). Also check out Rust examples using either WebAssembly's instantiate or instantiateStreaming.

Answer (score 2):

> `there was some error;  TypeError: "Response has unsupported MIME type"`
>   The Web server you are running does not understands/serves a MIME type `application/wasm`.

You can use a [rust based http server](https://crates.io/crates/https), it knows about wasm MIME type.

### Installation

Simply use curl

```
curl -SsL https://cdn.rawgit.com/thecoshman/http/master/install.sh | sh
```

and execute the downloaded script or you can explorer other ways to do the same at https://crates.io/crates/https.

---

### Running

Please use the downloaded server to server your Web Application(index.html).
e.g

```
cd ${YOUR_APPS_PATH}

http
```

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you. @peter-weyand

Answer (score 0):

A snippet of code for a workaround has been published on the WebAssembly Git [here](https://github.com/mdn/webassembly-examples/issues/5). Unfortunately, this is a workaround, and this defeats the purpose of `instantiateStreaming()` which is told [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running) to be "a lot more efficient", since the workaround needs an ArrayBuffer that `instantiateStreaming()` helps to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

[James Wilson's "wasm-fractal" project](https://github.com/jsdw/wasm-fractal/blob/da46fcc1c66d7bacb6a650ff9a6996d751079013/js/worker.js#L6) deals with the error, like this:

```js
importScripts("wasm_fractal.js");
delete WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming;
wasmFractal("./wasm_fractal_bg.wasm").then((wasm) => { 
  // establish connection between wasm and javascript
});
```

I use the `delete WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming;` trick myself during development, since my editor's builtin server, serves wasm with the incorrect mime type.