# Why do I get the error "Response has unsupported MIME type" after bundling Wasm together, but not when serving with the webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rust, webassembly

I am trying to make a Rust WebAssembly project and have modified the [rust-webpack-template](https://github.com/rustwasm/rust-webpack-template) as my starting point. The template is a webpack project with a JavaScript file that calls a single Wasm function and the Rust Wasm takes over from there.

I have modified the template  because I would like to have my main logic in JavaScript and call the Rust Wasm through an API.

I have changed the webpack entry to `bootstrap.js` shown below.

```
// bootstrap.js
import("./index.js").catch(e => 
    console.error("Error importing 'index.js':", e)
);
```

I added the file `index.js` and it calls the Rust Wasm functions

```
// index.js
import * as wasm from "../crate/pkg/rust_webpack";

const title = document.getElementById("msg");

title.innerText = wasm.get_msg();
```

The `get_msg` function from Rust looks like this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_msg() -> String {
    "Hello from Rust WebAssembly!".to_owned()
}
```

When I run the project using `webpack-dev-server -d`, everything works fine.

However, when I build the project using `webpack` and try and host the generated files directly, nothing is displayed and the browser console displays the error:

> Error importing 'index.js': TypeError: "Response has unsupported MIME type"

This error comes from the code in `bootstrap.js` but I'm not entirely sure what it means or how to fix this error.

Why do things work when serving with the webpack dev server but not after bundling everything together?

Comment: *and host the generated files directly* — **how** do you host them? Look at the MIME type of the files in your browser's network inspector in both cases; presumably they differ. Then figure out why they don't match. Then figure out how to make them match.

Comment: For how I host them, I have tried both a bare bones `express.js` server to statically host the directory webpack exports to, as well as accessing the files directly through `file:///`. I get the same error in both cases.

Comment: For the network inspector, everything shows to have been successful. I'm not sure exactly how webpack works, but in reality there are no `index.js` or `bootstrap.js` files. There are only `bundle.js`, `1.bundle.js`, and one seemingly randomly named `.module.wasm` file. All show to have been acquired successfully.

Comment: I'd expect the network transfer to be fine. What do the headers of those files say the MIME types are in the cases it works and doesn't?

Comment: For `.js` the content-type is `application/javascript`, and for the `module.wasm` file it is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I have also found chrome gives a slightly more detailed error: `TypeError: Failed to execute "compile" on "WebAssembly": Incorrect response MIME type. Expected "application/wasm"`

Comment: I think that may be enough to get me to the solution. I will give an update if I can get things working from here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) helped me to figure out in the comments, the MIME type of the .wasm file is being set to `application/octet-stream` when the browser expects it to be `application/wasm`.

I am using a simple [express](https://expressjs.com/) server to host my files. Express can be configured to use the correct MIME type with a single line.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Set the MIME type explicitly
express.static.mime.define({'application/wasm': ['wasm']});

app.use(express.static('./dist'));

app.listen(3000);
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3589), express will handle .wasm files correctly after version 4.17. It works correctly in webpack dev server because they implemented their own [workaround](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/1580) while they wait for the fix in express.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when hosting statically in an s3 bucket (I'd imagine the same would happen if I was hosting on ipfs). Any ideas? https://web3.unegma.com/page-three

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem ("Response has unsupported MIME type") with Flask. The problem was that I **didn't** have a separate route to the `.wasm` file. For example:

```py
@app.route('/path/to/file.wasm')
def wasm_file():
    return send_file('/path/to/file.wasm', mimetype = 'application/wasm');
```

It is not the answer to this question, but it's a hint for other people who have a similar problem.

Comment: All credit goes to Discord Rust channel user `@Pauan`

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this problem, leading me to change my .htaccess file (I'm using Apache to host my local server) to include the following:
`AddType application/wasm wasm`

If the error persists, and you are getting this error from using `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming`, this related question may have an explanation and workaround: [WebAssembly InstantiateStreaming Wrong MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239924/webassembly-instantiatestreaming-wrong-mime-type)